# Replace match after the start of the line and another pattern

Tags: sed, grep, regular-expression

I'm trying to delete a character that is at the start of the line of multiple string, but, also have another pattern just before the start of the line, which i don't want to delete:

```
1:string:test...
2:string test
3:etc...
```

to

```
1 string:test...
2 string test
3 etc...
```

Some string can also contain the character `:` which make things interesting. So far i tried:

`echo "1:test:" | grep -Pv '(?<=\d):'`

which does match the `:` character (at least it highlight it, so I'm guessing it's matched) but it doesn't get omitted when using the `-v` flag, maybe because it's on the same line as the match? (Here i only did experiment on how to match it and remove it instead of replacing it with a space, as the aforementioned example showed)

`echo "1:test:" | sed 's/^.:./ /g'`

This seems to be the closest i got, but it cut off the rest of the start beside the `:` character, which give:

`est:`

instead of

`1 test:`

Comment: You say you want to delete a pattern after another pattern.  I guess the second pattern (the one that you want to delete) is `:` (colon); what’s the first one?  What do you want to do with input like `42:days`, `foo:bar`, `The quick:brown fox` or `:quux`?  For that matter, what do you want to do with input that doesn’t contain any colons?  Also, you say that you want to delete the colon, but then you show the output you want, and the colons have been ***replaced*** by spaces.

Comment: This is a trivial problem (unless there’s more here than meets the eye, which seems unlikely).  And the OP already knows the answer; they don’t need our help.  And the title is so arcane, and the wording of the question is so unclear, that nobody who has this problem will ever find this question.

Comment: it is, but i didn't have the solution right away, and only until a couple minutes/hour pass, and so i just answered myself...thought it was a waste to delete this since it might help someone.

Comment: And to be honest, there is dozen more of more popular and "trivial" question, especially about regex, so i wouldn't say it's useless, even if it's easy to answer from a certain perspective.

Comment: btw...why should it be closed when it's already answered?

Comment: IMO it should be closed because it’s not helpful. As I said, you don’t need help anymore and it is unlikely to benefit anybody else. Also because it’s still unclear, as you haven’t answered my question about what must appear before the colon for it to be subject to replacement. (Oh, I just noticed: the question is internally inconsistent. In the first half, you say `1:string:` should be changed to `1 string:`, but in the second half you say `1:test:` should be changed to `1 text` (deleting the second colon).) That’s my opinion; now let’s sit back and see whether the other voting members agree.

Comment: I concede about the second half which had an error (and that i just corrected) but beside that, it still is helpful to anyone who find this. Though i do agree that this should be closed (as i don't need help anymore) and it is obvious that beside me, other would agree to close this too, saying `now let’s sit back and see whether the other voting members agree` isn't gonna change anything since it's obvious this will happen (where even me agree to that).

Comment: There’s an excellent science-fiction/fantasy novel called *The Hitchhiker’s Guide to the Galaxy,* by Douglas Adams.  Arthur, the hero (or at least the main character), has just learned that his house has been condemned and scheduled for destruction *right now.*  He is told that the plans have been on display in the local planning office.  “On display? I eventually had to go down to the cellar to find them.” / «That’s the display department.» / “With a flashlight.” / «Ah, well, the lights had probably gone.» / “So had the stairs.” / «But look, you found the notice, didn’t you?» … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  “Yes,” said Arthur, “yes I did. It was on display in the bottom of a locked file cabinet stuck in a disused lavatory with a sign on the door saying ‘Beware of the Leopard.’ ” … … … … … … … … … … That’s how likely it is for somebody who can benefit from this answer to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works:

`echo -e "1:test:\n2:test\n3:test:\n" | sed '/:/s// /'`

Print

```
1 test:
2 test
3 test:
```

Comment: Or just ``sed 's/:/ /'``

Answer (score 0):

Python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
k=re.compile(":")
m=open('filename','r')
for i in m:
    print i.replace(":"," ",1).strip()
```

awk  command works only for mentioned example

```
awk  -F ":" '{print substr($0,1,1),substr($0,3)}' filename
```

sed command

```
  sed "s/:/ /1" filename
```